# How to print each lists values in Haskell

Tags: haskell

I have a list of lists like `[[a,c,e],[b,d,f]]` and I was wondering how to print out every value from the lists, one at a time from each list.

The order I want when I print is `abcdef`.

I've been thinking about this for a while but I can't seem to figure it out.

Comment: You could "concat" the list to get `[a,c,e,b,d,f]`, and then print it. Ah, but that's the wrong order. It's printing the row-major order of your matrix, but you seek the column major order. If only there were a way to [transpose](https://www.haskell.org/hoogle/?hoogle=transpose) a matrix before you [concat](https://www.haskell.org/hoogle/?hoogle=concat)...

Answer (score 1):

How's the following

```
concat $ transpose [[1,2,3],[4,5,6]]
```

returns

```
[1,4,2,5,3,6]

mapM_ (putStr . show) [1,4,3,5,3,6]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
combine :: [a] -> [a] -> [a]
combine [] ys = ys
combine (x:xs) ys = x:combine ys xs

main :: IO ()
main = do
    print (combine [1,3,5] [2,4,6])
    return ()
```

outputs: [1,2,3,4,5,6]